# Displaying Image from image uploader

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

im trying to display image from database by calling filename of the image. 
here's my code.

```
$fname=$row['user'];
$query1=mysql_query("select * from user where username = '$fname'");

$q_pix =mysql_fetch_array($query1);
$id=$row['id'];
$date=$row['date'];
$message=$row['message'];
$lugar=$row['location'];

<img src=".$row['location']." height=\"120\" width=\"120\">
```

Undefined index: location.

Comment: It simply means your result set (data from your mysql) doesnt have that field `location` modify your mysql query to include that field too

Answer (score 1):

First of all `print` both the variables `$row` and `$q_pix` and check in which you have your location field.

Try to use `$q_pix` variable in img src if it has -

```
<img src=".$q_pix['location']." height=\"120\" width=\"120\">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $fname = $row['user'];
    $query1 = mysql_query("select * from user where username = '$fname'");
    $q_pix = mysql_fetch_array($query1);
?>
```

Here you are getting values from database to the variable `$q_pix`, not to `$row`.
So retrieve values from $q_pix instead of $row. (Print both `$q_pix` and `$row` to make   sure they are getting values).

```
<?php
    $id = $q_pix['id'];
    $date = $q_pix['date'];
    $message = $q_pix['message'];
    $lugar = $q_pix['location'];
?>
<img src="<?php echo $q_pix['location']; ?>" height=\"120\" width=\"120\">
```

NOTE : Make sure your `$q_pix['location']` value includes the directory stucture too with the image name.